# jboss fuse split List property

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have a proxy, which take a `RequestBean` as argument, which contains a `list` property and I need to split this list property using split EIP.

I tried

```
    <split streaming="true">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
        <process ref="requestHeaderProcessor" />
    </split>
```

My Complete route is

```
<route id="httpBridge">
    <from uri="cxf:bean:splitterOperation?dataFormat=POJO" />
    <split streaming="true">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
        <bean ref="requestHeaderProcessor" method="process" />
    </split>
    <to uri="cxf:bean:realService" />
</route>
```

My Proxy Service method signature is

```
public List<ResponseBean> splitList(List<RequestContent> requestBean);
```

ResponseBean.java

```
ResponseBean {

private String name;

}
```

RequestBean.java

```
RequestBean {

private String list;

}
```

The processor is not receiving individual `RequestContent`, I want the processor to receive `RequestContent` individually.

tried printing following line and

```
System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody().getClass().getName());
```

and got `java.util.ArrayList`. So its 100% Iteratable.

But, when I print the

```
System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
```

I am getting

```
[webservice.RequestContent@10128f3, webservice.RequestContent@1277137]
```

Which is list of all the `RequestContent`.

But, why am I seeing the list in the bean, the Exchange must contain only one `RequestContent` according to split definition (Since, it processes sequentially).

Where am I making mistake. or is this the way it works. How can I make sure it splits the content?

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever this method returns is what is used for splitting

```
 <simple>${body.requestBean.requestContent}</simple>
```

So make sure that is a List or array, or can be iterated

Comment: Thank you so much, I have modified the code to get List property from body, still not working. please check the modified code.

Comment: As camel-cxf puts the invocation parameter into a list, you need to take first parameter just like this. <simple>${body[0]}<simple>